# iPhone - How add a final line in a UITableView to add items, preventing rearranging of this line

Tags: iphone, uitableview, editing

I have a `UITableView` put in edited mode.

```
 self.tableView.editing = YES;
```

In this table view, I have some lines displayed in a custom cell, and I'd like to add one at the end that would allow the user to add an item (using another view).

So I wrote some lines :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return "number of lines" + 1;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row+1 != [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]) {   
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    } 
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row + 1 == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Add a line...";
    }
    else {
        do the stuff in the custom cell
    }
}
```

Doing this way, the `UITableView` allows to rearrange any line. I can move the first line after the "add line", and move the "add line" in first position.

How may I remove the arrange button on the "add line" cell and prevent other lines to go under this one ?

Or is there a better way to code this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([indexPath row] != INDEX_OF_SPECIAL_ROW)
}
```

and

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath 
       toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    if ([proposedDestinationIndexPath row] < NUMBER_OF_ROWS)
    {
        return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
    }

    NSIndexPath *otherPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NUMBER_OF_ROWS-1 inSection:0];

    return otherPath;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The much easier way would be to set a [**tableFooterView**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView). You can place any **UIView** in there, so not only are you allowed to add a **UITableViewCell** but also a completely custom subclass. Doing it this way you will avoid all the unnecessary checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone
```

For that row in `- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

And check out [– tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3amoveRowAtIndexPath%3atoIndexPath%3a)